# Does a SubClass object in an ArrayList<SuperClass> keep methods unique to SubClass?

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist

Basically what the title says, but some elaboration. I have a SuperClass with a couple of SubClasses. I needed an ArrayList to hold both types of Subclasses so hence the ArrayList of type SuperClass. I tried to access Subclass1's `getQuantity()` method using `ArrayList.get(0).getQuantity();` (assuming that index 0 is of type SubClass1). I get the error: getQuantity is undefined for the type SuperClass.

Do the SubClass objects not keep their properties when put into a SuperClass ArrayList? And if they do keep their properties, how do I access them?

Comment: Initially this may sound like a duplicate, but after about 20 minutes of research, some posts touched on the same topic, but did not exactly answer my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The objects themselves are still a `subclass`, but when you get them out of the collection it only knows about the `superclass` so it can't tell you which is which, it has to pick the common denominator.

If you know exactly that a specific index holds an object of type `Subclass` you can just cast it:

```
Subclass myObject = (Subclass) list.get(0);
System.out.println(myObject.getQuantity());
```

And it should work.

And a safer way requires testing if the object is really what you think it is:

```
SuperClass myObject = list.get(0);
if ( myObject instanceof Subclass) {
  Subclass mySubObject = (Subclass) myObject;
  System.out.println(mySubObject.getQuantity());
}
```

The first example raises an exception if the object is not of type `Subclass`, the second one wouldn't since it tests before to make sure.

What you need to understand here is that `SuperClass myObject = list.get(0)` is not the object itself, but a reference to access the object in memory. Think about it as a remote that allows you to control your object, in this case, it's not a fully featured remote, since it doesn't show you all your object can do, so you can switch to a better one (as in `Subclass myObject = (Subclass) list.get(0)`) to be able to access all features.

I'd surely recommend the [Head First Java book](http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfjava/) as it covers this stuff in great detail (and I stole this remote example from there).

Comment: Good answer. I wonder if in the future Oracle will address this problem or just leave it. Heck it may be some sort of use but I can't think of any.

Comment: This is not a problem, that's how object oriented languages (and generics) work, you can't say your list contains `Subclass` only, since it doesn't and the compiler **has** to enforce that.

Comment: I will be buying Head First Design Patterns after this semester :) also, what I was getting at is, I wonder if they will add something that automatically switches "remotes" without having to say I'm switching "remotes". I think it could be useful.

Comment: They might build a pattern matcher into the language that could help with that, would avoid the ugly `instanceof` sequences, but this is usually a sign of bad design (as @chrylis other solution pointed out) and you should avoid this kind of style as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

All of the objects retain their own class identity, but the code that uses the `ArrayList` isn't directly aware of it. As far as it's concerned, the `ArrayList` only holds references to `SuperClass`-type objects, and it can only call `SuperClass`'s methods on objects it retrieves from it.

The calling code *can* use `instanceof` or similar techniques to find out if a particular object in a collection is of a subtype, but this is usually bad practice, since it usually indicates mixing of the different levels of abstraction. The one case where this is generally considered reasonable is if the subclass has some optional high-performance characteristic that the caller can take advantage of (and that measurement has determined is worth complicating the code for); one example might be that while `List`'s `get()` method is has no performance guarantees, some implementations, like `ArrayList`, also implement `RandomAccess`, which indicates that there's no performance penalty to using `get()` in any order.

Comment: What I'm seeing though is there's not much other way unless you restructure it so that ArrayList doesn't contain two types of SubClasses?

Comment: @comscis Right, but that's *usually* the Right Thing to do. If you care about the difference between `SubClass1` and `SubClass2`, you usually shouldn't throw them in one collection together but should keep them in different ones.

Comment: good info to know. For my purposes, though I need them in the same ArrayList. One SubClass is an Expense, and the other is an Income. I wanna keep track of them in the order they are added. Separating them adds a lot of complexity so, I'll cut corners this time ;) but I can see where it might be trouble.

Comment: @comscis Depending on what methods specifically you want to call on `Income` and `Expense`, the right approach might be to add an `abstract` method on `Entry` that the code with the `List` can call. That way it knows that it can call "the right thing for whichever subclass" without having to know which subclass a particular object is.

Comment: Interesting idea. I will keep that in mind for my next project!

Comment: just out of curiosity in this context. can I create an arraylist<interface> rather than <superclass>. if yes I could switch - case a getId(), defined in the interface, rather than do an expensive instanceof .. ?

Comment: @MichaelD. Yes, you could, and Don't Do That. (1) `instanceof` isn't all that expensive, and (2) you're setting your data structures up wrong if you think you need to do that sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

When you have some ArrayList and you fill it with things that extend SuperClass you have to check instanceof and cast to get to the methods specific to those subclasses.

Example:

```
ArrayList<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>;
animals.add(new Duck());
animals.add(new Cow());
animals.add(new Horse());

for (Animal animal : animals) 
   if (animal instanceof Horse) {
      Horse horse = (Horse)animal;
      horse.gallop();
   }
```