# How do I create an ArrayList filled with different types of objects?

Tags: java, list, generics, inheritance, arraylist

I have different classes for a bank system. These classes are;

- SavingsAccount
- StudentAccount
- NormalAccount

Now I want to create an ArrayList and populate it with objects of all these different classes, e.g. first element being studentaccount1, second element being, savingsaccount 2... and so on.

So I tried using the object type:

```
List<Object> accountList = new ArrayList<>();
```

But with this approach, for some reason I'm unable to access the values stored in the class variables, for example:

```
accountList.add(saving1);
```

`accountList.get(saving1)` doesn't bring up the methods declared in those classes.

So how could I fix this, or implement it in some kind of another way?

EDIT:

I forgot to mention that Normal account is the parent class and both `StudentAccount` and `SavingsAccount` are subclasses.

Therefore I realized that I can just declare the ArrayList as the `NormalAccount` type (parent class type) instead and achieve what I wanted.

Comment: What is the class hierarchy among these classes?

Comment: Do you have a parent class for the three account classes?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20295671/does-a-subclass-object-in-an-arraylistsuperclass-keep-methods-unique-to-subcla

Comment: The NormalAccount is a parent class, Student and Savings are both subclasses inherited from NormalAccount

Comment: You could create a hierarchy among these objects, it seems a BankAccount class could serve as parent to these classes you have here. And then you could add base methods to your parent, and account-specific methods to your child classes. then list would be : List<BankAccount> list = new ArrayList<>(); when you get, you need to check which instance is what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access the methods of the classes. Instead, you can only access methods of `Object` class in your example.

I think you can put common methods declarations in an interface or abstract class, then implement them.

> I forgot to mention that Normal account is the parent class and both
>   "StudentAccount" and "SavingsAccount" are subclasses.
>
> So can I just declare the ArrayList as a "NormalAccount" type and then
>   be able to access the variables?

Yes, exactly. You can define it like,

```
List<NormalAccount> accountList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an interface `Account` with common methods and make all these accounts implement it.

```
public class SavingsAccount implements Account { ... }
```

Then create a list of the type implementing this interface.

```
List<Account> accountList = new ArrayList<>();
```

I don't recommend you to create a *marker interface* just for this purpose. It's a bad idea. An interface should have public methods.

Alternatively, the `Account` can be an (abstract) class itself and these specific accounts would extend from it - include there the common functionality to avoid the code duplicity. It depends what exactly do you want to achieve and which one fits your design.

Edit:

You missed to disclose us a quite significant fact that `NormalAccount` is the parent of the others. Thus the solution is quite simple then:

```
List<NormalAccount> accountList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class have suffix `_Account` so I guess they have similar fields.

Make a super class for them, either interface or class:

```
public class Account {
}

public class StudentAccount extends Account {
}
```

Then declare your list as:

```
List<Account> accountList = new ArrayList<>();

Account normal = new NormalAccount();
accountList.add(normal);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the Object class, during retrieval of data, you need to cast the retrieved data to be able to use the methods. Try something like this:

> (SavingsAccount) accountList.get(saving1)

you will be able to access the methods