# Access method within sub-class

Tags: kotlin, multiple-inheritance

I am fiddling with Kotlin and attempting to create a simple creature hierarchy. I appear to have been able to do this successfully however, I am unable to access the "think" method in my "Head : Appendage" class that is a child of the Human : Creature class

I can see the subclass printed out all the way to the head class but I am unable to run the think() method

```
val human = Human()
println(human.appendages["Head"])           // [Head@3803641]
println(human.appendages["Head"]?.get(0))   // Head@3803641
human.appendages["Head"]?.get(0).think()    // uncaught reference
```

```
import org.omg.CORBA.Object
import java.util.*

open class Creature {
    var appendages = HashMap<String,ArrayList<Appendage>>()
}
open class Appendage {
    constructor() {}
}
open class Human : Creature {
    constructor()
    {
        appendages["Arm"] = ArrayList<Appendage>()
        appendages["Arm"]?.add(Arm())
        appendages["Arm"]?.add(Arm())
        appendages["Leg"] = ArrayList<Appendage>()
        appendages["Leg"]?.add(Leg())
        appendages["Leg"]?.add(Leg())
        appendages["Head"] = ArrayList<Appendage>()
        appendages["Head"]?.add(Head("Human"))
    }
}
class Alien : Creature
{
    constructor()
    {
        appendages["Tentacle"] = ArrayList<Appendage>()
        appendages["Tentacle"]?.add(Tentacle())
        appendages["Tentacle"]?.add(Tentacle())
        appendages["Tentacle"]?.add(Tentacle())
        appendages["Tentacle"]?.add(Tentacle())
        appendages["Arm"] = ArrayList<Appendage>()
        appendages["Arm"]?.add(Arm())
        appendages["Arm"]?.add(Arm())
        appendages["Leg"] = ArrayList<Appendage>()
        appendages["Leg"]?.add(Leg())
        appendages["Leg"]?.add(Leg())
        appendages["Head"] = ArrayList<Appendage>()
        appendages["Head"]?.add(Head("Alien"))
        appendages["Head"]?.add(Head("Alien"))
    }
}

class Head : Appendage {
    private var whatami : String = ""
    constructor(whatami : String)
    {
        this.whatami = whatami
    }
    public fun think()
    {
        println("$whatami Thinking")
    }
}
open class Arm : Appendage {
    private var rotation = mutableListOf<Int>(0,0,0)
    constructor() {}
    fun rotateX(degrees: Int)
    {
        rotation[0] = degrees
    }
    fun rotateY(degrees: Int)
    {
        rotation[1] = degrees
    }
    fun rotateZ(degrees: Int)
    {
        rotation[2] = degrees
    }
}
open class Leg : Appendage {
    private var rotation = mutableListOf<Int>(0,0,0)
    constructor() {}
    fun rotateX(degrees: Int)
    {
        rotation[0] = degrees
    }
    fun rotateY(degrees: Int)
    {
        rotation[1] = degrees
    }
    fun rotateZ(degrees: Int)
    {
        rotation[2] = degrees
    }
}
open class Tentacle : Appendage {
    private var rotation = mutableListOf<Int>(0,0,0)
    constructor() {}
    fun rotateX(degrees: Int)
    {
        rotation[0] = degrees
    }
    fun rotateY(degrees: Int)
    {
        rotation[1] = degrees
    }
    fun rotateZ(degrees: Int)
    {
        rotation[2] = degrees
    }
}
```

I expect the program to print "Human Thinking" but I am getting an "uncaught reference" error

Comment: How should the compiler know that `human.appendages["Head"]?.get(0)` contains an Object of type `Head`? All it knows is that it is `Appendage` and nothing else. You would need to cast here (e.g. `(human.appendages["Head"]?.get(0) as Head).think()`. You should also look into data classes and primary constructors, those Kotlin features would help you to reduce boilerplate code.

Comment: The rules to Java are very similar in this subject, so this could be a duplicate and useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20295671/does-a-subclass-object-in-an-arraylistsuperclass-keep-methods-unique-to-subcla

Answer (score 0):

as Tom said, your compiler dont know anything about the type. you need make a simple cast like this:

```
(human.appendages["Head"]?.get(0) as Head).think()
```